# Is it possible to change background color of main body for multiple pages?

Tags: css, plotly-dash

My dashboard has multiple pages, each page contain top navigation bar and container.

In my style.css file there is only one body to change background color of body, currently I change background colors of container.

My question is: is it possible to change background color of whole body when switching from one page to the other page?

```css
page1_layout = html.Div([navbar_page1, container_page1])
page2_layout = html.Div([navbar_page2, container_page2])

container_page1 = html.Div([top_info_page1, grid_container_page1]
container_page2 = html.Div([top_info_page2, grid_container_page2]


:root {
    --text-color: #798d8f;
    --tab-color: #212529;
}

/* Add background color to entire app */
body {
    background-color: var(--text-color);
  }

#container-page1 {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
}

#container-page2 {
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    background-color: #DADADA;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can give a class/id to the body element and set the specific class/id background color

```html
    <body id="page1">content</body>
```

```html
    <body id="page2">content</body>
```

```css
body{
background: red;
}
#page2{
background: blue !important;
}
```

Comment: how to assign id to body tag inside dash ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor= 'the color';
```

Comment: how to use it inside dash .py files ?